# Including a relative path to a class file

Tags: filesystem-access

I'm trying to set the documentclass type of a certain `.tex` file to be a class that is in the parent folder. However, I'm not sure how to include the path to the `.cls` file. I can write

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{../foo}
```

But that complains that the imported class isn't the same as the provided class (in `foo.cls` I have `\ProvidesClass{foo}`. I know that this is just a warning and I could ignore it, or I could write `\ProvidesClass{../foo}`, but was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do the document class declaration.

Comment: I don't think you can use a path when selecting the `\documentclass`. Instead you should change the search path so it can be found.

Comment: A path does seem to work, though. Or is that only guaranteed to work in certain environments? (I'd rather not place them in some central folder since each is only relevant to a certain group of work)

Comment: I belive that the document class that is expected will be `../foo` and not `foo` when you use it as `\documentclass{../foo}`. Perhaps you could try changing the class name to `../foo` but I think that is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question, changing the provides "../foo" will work, but it does seem a bit ugly.

Comment: I meant use `\documentclass{foo}` and change the search path so that TeX can locate it. ie., Place the file in `~/texmf/tex/latex/`, and run `texhash` to update the TeX database.  I haven't tried it but it should work.

Comment: The problem with that is my documentclasses are meant only to apply to a specific set of documents all in a single folder, and it seems bad to put all of them inside a global area.

Comment: As @PeterGrill pointed out in the comments above, it is better to place it at the proper place. Please cf. [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable to locally change the search paths.

### Unix

Run

```
export TEXINPUTS="..:"
```

before your LaTeX commands. Or set the variable only for one command:

```
TEXINPUTS="..:" pdflatex …
```

### Windows

Run

```
set TEXINPUTS="..;"
```

to set the environment variable in a current command line shell or batch file session.