# Texmaker Sty-File in Subfolder

Tags: errors, texmaker

I have many sty-files in a subfolder next to my tex-file:

When I run pdfLaTeX it doesn't find the sty-files. I found the solution with

```
export TEXINPUTS=".:./sty:"
```

But where I can include that in Texmaker?

Comment: Based on [Including a relative path to a class file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27417/5764) you need to run this from the terminal...

Comment: If you use `Linux`, I would say: Execute the statement in a terminal or store it to `.bashrc` ;-)