# Warning: some font shapes not available when compiling twenty-seconds-cv

Tags: fonts, xetex, texlive-2019

I'm trying to compile [twenty-seconds-cv](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex) but I can't get the font right unfortunately. I'm on Ubuntu and installed Texlive as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373). Everything seems to work fine, except for the font in the twenty-seconds-cv template. I'm compiling with xelatex fwiw.

These are the warning I get in my log file:

> LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class
>   `../tscv/twentysecondcv',
>                  but the document class provides`twentysecondcv'.

I changed the reference to the package in my tex file to fit my directory structure like this:

```
\documentclass[]{../tscv/twentysecondcv}
```

Not sure if this is already a problem.

Then towards the end of the log I get these warnings:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ClearSans(0)/m/sc' undefined (Font)
>   using`T1/ClearSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 38.
>   ...
>   ...  (other things happening but no warning)
>   ...
>   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ClearSans(0)/m/it' undefined (Font)
>   using`T1/ClearSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 64.
>   ...
>   ...  (other things happening but no warning)
>   ...
>   LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults
>   substituted.
>   LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get
>   cross-references right

When I run `locate ClearSans` I get this output:

> /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/clearsans/ClearSans.map
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-ly1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-ly1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-ot1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-t1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-t1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-ts1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-ts1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-ly1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-ly1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-ot1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-t1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-t1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-ts1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-ts1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-ly1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-ly1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-ot1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-t1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-t1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-ts1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-ts1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-ly1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-ly1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-ot1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-t1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-t1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-ts1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-ts1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-ly1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-ly1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-ot1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-t1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-t1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-ts1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-ts1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-ly1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-ly1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-ot1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-t1--base.tfm /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-t1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-ts1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-ts1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-ly1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-ly1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-ot1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-t1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-t1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-ts1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-ts1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-ly1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-ly1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-ot1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-t1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-t1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-ts1--base.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-ts1.tfm
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold.ttf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic.ttf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic.ttf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light.ttf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium.ttf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic.ttf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Regular.ttf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin.ttf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold.pfb
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic.pfb
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic.pfb
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light.pfb
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium.pfb
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic.pfb
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Regular.pfb
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin.pfb
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-ly1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-t1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Bold-lf-ts1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-ly1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-t1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-ts1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-ly1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-t1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Italic-lf-ts1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-ly1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-t1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Light-lf-ts1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-ly1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-t1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Medium-lf-ts1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-ly1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-t1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-ts1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-ly1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-t1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-Thin-lf-ts1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-ly1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-t1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/intel/clearsans/ClearSans-lf-ts1.vf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/ClearSans.sty
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/LY1ClearSans-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/LY1ClearSansLight-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/LY1ClearSansThin-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/OT1ClearSans-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/OT1ClearSansLight-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/OT1ClearSansThin-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/T1ClearSans-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/T1ClearSansLight-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/T1ClearSansThin-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/TS1ClearSans-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/TS1ClearSansLight-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/clearsans/TS1ClearSansThin-LF.fd
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/ClearSans-Bold-lf-t1.htf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/ClearSans-BoldItalic-lf-t1.htf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/ClearSans-Italic-lf-t1.htf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/ClearSans-Light-lf-t1.htf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/ClearSans-Medium-lf-t1.htf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/ClearSans-MediumItalic-lf-t1.htf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/ClearSans-Thin-lf-t1.htf
>   /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/ClearSans-lf-t1.htf

I actually wanted to post the whole log file, but it was above the character limit for StackExchange. Feel free to ask if you need more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document is meant to be used with pdfLaTeX, not with XeLaTeX, so it loads `fontenc` with the `T1` option. The font on the other hand auto detects the engine and prepares the font with the fontencoding `TU` if XeLaTeX is used. You can fix this either by using pdfLaTeX or by manually changing back to the fontencoding `TU`:
Add to your preable (directly after `\documentclass{...}`) the line

```
\usepackage[TU]{fontenc}
```

Then you get the right font.

You might notice that you still get the warning

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ClearSans(0)/m/sc' undefined (Font)
>   using`TU/ClearSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 37.

That's a bug in the class and you can ignore it, the `sc` font is only "used" for some icons where `sc` is ignored anyway.

This together with all kinds of other warnings and encoding problems even in the example document gives the impression that the whole template might not be very well-written will lead to lots of additional problems later on. So I can not recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now! What about the first warning I get though? Am I including the template correctly by changing `\documentclass[]{twentysecondcv}` to `\documentclass[]{../tscv/twentysecondcv}` to fit my directory structure or is there a better way to include files/packages?

Comment: @c_student See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27417/including-a-relative-path-to-a-class-file You are not supposed to add a path to the documentclass, instead you can add the path to TeX's searchpath.